# JAVAFX What other ways are there to make a Label blink, instead of using the timeline?

Tags: java, javafx, label, timeline, blink

How do I create the blinking effect on my custom label other than using the timer?

Here's a workable example I am using...

**The custom label class**

```
public class CustomLabel extends Label{

   public CustomLabel(String text1){
      super(text1);
      setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

      //for blinking effect
        TIMER = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),ae->ChangeColor1()),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2),ae->ChangeColor2())
        );
        TIMER.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        TIMER.play();
    }

    public void ChangeColor1(){
        setTextFill(Color.Pink);    
    }

    public void ChangeColor2(){
        setTextFill(Color.Blue);    
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
StackPane sp = new StackPane(new CustomLabel("Testing"));
Scene sc = new Scene(sp)
primaryStage.setScene(sc)
sc.show();
```

Is there any way to make this method "lighter"?

Somehow this method causes an error after keeping the app running for 1 full day

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Any advise on how to get around this? This app is required to be running for more than 1 full day.

Comment: Well that's interesting... you get the OOME just from running the code you posted? If so, that's a bug.

Comment: you can set an autoReverse on the timeline so you don't have to set both colours. `TIMER.setAutoReverse(true);` its also possible that as it keeps making new keyframes as it is constantly running it doesn't get a chance to go to the recycle bin it will fill the memory, perhaps just a very big cycleCount might be the answer (if its for a button is it likely that they are going to have it sit on that button for a whole day?)

Comment: @James_D yup, initially when my app does not have this blinking effect, it can run for days without any error thrown.

Comment: TL;DR Fill transition is what you're looking for? Maybe you'll want a discrete interpolator to make the changes suddenly instead of gradually.

Comment: @MouseEvent I think the blink he wants changes the colour of the button not just fade it, but the FadeTransition is a great way to do it if you didn't care so much about making it a different colour and just blink.

Comment: @TravisF Corrected my comment.

Comment: @TravisF hmm... how do I do it with a FadeTransition? Do you guys have any examples

Comment: Ronaldo, you can check the Oracle Guides to basic transition/animation effects [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm) it has an example of fadeTransition.

Comment: Btw just read javadoc, fill transition only works with shapes for some reason. So you can either use `Text` instead of a label, or stack 2 labels with the 2 colors one on top of the other and fade the top.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use CSS. Define a custom pseudoclass: `PseudoClass blink = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("blink");`. Then have a single keyframe in your timeline with `e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(blink, ! getPseudoClassStates().contains(blink))`. Finally, define an external CSS with `.label { -fx-text-fill: pink ; }` and `.label:blink { -fx-text-fill: blue ;}`. (Not posting as answer as I have no idea if this will solve the problem.)

Comment: The out of memory is probably because you are creating multiple labels during the use of your application, but the timeline's are not cleaned up (and they refer to the label, which refers to its container, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

to reply to your above answer, (as the comments do not allow for code blocks) this is the way you will need to do it for it to be able to "blink":

```
KeyFrame kfP = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(ae.textFillProperty(), Color.PINK));
Timeline TIMER = new Timeline();
TIMER.getKeyFrames().add(kfP);
TIMER.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
TIMER.setAutoReverse(true);
TIMER.play();
```

The reason to do it this way is you only create one keyframe and it only uses the one keyframe, this stops the timeline from creating multiple new keyframes as it would in your initial code and as the timeline continues to run it does not get Garbage collected so it just builds until your out of memory.